# Java equivalent of .net recycle

Tags: java

What is the Java equivalent of the .net Recycle for web apps in IIS.

This is when using Java on a linux machine outside of IIS.

Is it just to stop and start the application?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: After using Java for a long time, I have played around a little with .Net and IIS. I just think the ability to recycle an App pool is very good and would like to know if there is an equivalent in Java as it would to a temp solution for memory leaks.

Comment: @Paul restarting an app to address a problem is a hack/workaround not a solution.

Comment: If you perform restart just to avoid memory leaks, it will produce more possible problems in future than you find and fix critical code. I suggest to you - read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410413/benefits-and-hindrances-of-regular-server-reboots for quick info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really - IIS and JVM work in different ways. When you say recycling in IIS, it's basically restarting the Worker process. Each Web Application deployed to IIS is under an  application pool and worker process.

In case of java, it's not like that. The whole App server runs on a jvm and you have different Web applications deployed into the App server which runs within the app server.

You could use DB connection pools or Apache commons pool for pooling (Some of your expensive objects you reuse) which can be refreshed but not exactly in a way like IIS.

> Even though this would be a nice feature - in reality if you ever
>   reach a situation of needing to refresh application pool, your
>   code/dll(may be 3rd party) is the culprit. There would definitely be a
>   memory leak which needs to be addressed! Also when you recycle the session state might be lost. Apparently users logged in would get logged out (and if they are in the middle of a transaction they might loose data).So it could lead to a very volatile situation!

**Update**

You could use stuff like [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/overview) which handles memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Usually JEE servlet containers offer the option of reloading the application. i.e. Tomcat has a Reload button for each app on the manager console.

It also has a button that triggers a full garbage collection, by the way.